# Password Encryption inside a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskscheduler

I have a windows bat which is called by the Windows task scheduler every 5 mins. In there I am connecting to a network drive, something like this
net use G: \hostname\shared mypassword /user:myuserid /persistent:yes 
it works with no issue, but I don't want to put the password in the bat file as a plain txt. is there anyway to protect my password or put a encrypted password or store it somewhere safe in there to make it secure?

Answer (score 1):

Use an environment variable.

```
 Net use .... %password%
```

Then define the variable in the context which the batch runs. This is better than script source because the script is *mobile*, it can be copied from this machine to that, it can end up in the source control and so on. It is not more secure against a local host attack, i.e.  If one user could see the password in the script it is also likely to find it in the environment.

There are more advanced solutions if you are willing to switch to PowerShell. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Md5 generator](https://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) (or hash code generator written by your own) to generate a password from any file in your computer. Whenever you run it, the batch file will generate the password from that specific file by the generator.

Your password is no longer in plain text, but hidden in generator and the corresponding file.

hope it helps.

Comment: nice idea for *generating* a password. Be sure to choose a file that doesn't change. But the question was to use an already *existing* password without writing it "clear text" into the batchfile.

Comment: You can simply hashed the password into Md5 string and save the hash code string into a text file. And use the generator to read the string. It will still use the existing password.